# Merging new commits on older branch to dev

Tags: git, version-control

We got unusual requirement from the client where we needed to give a new feature in the product for older release. Our branch structure is as below.

[image: master ----> c1 -> c2 -> .... r1 ->]

We have three branches `master`, `release 1` and `release 2` (names are not real). We c1, c2, r1, c3, c4 etc are commits on master branch and respective commits for other branches in show in same fashion. We had to make changes for release 1 branch and we made several commits on the same branch to complete the feature. Not we want to merge those changes to master branch, what could be the best way? I know about `cherry-pick` option but as there are so many commits that it looks lot of work and there are chances to miss some of them. Is `merge` a option there? How can I carry this out?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use git merge. According to the documentation:https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

[image]

This is exactly what you want to do in your demand: replace topic by release 1.

So you should:

```
git checkout master
git merge "release 1"
```

All the changes from branch release 1 will be replayed on top of the master branch, since they diverged, and a new merge commit will be created.